# C EOF symbolic value and signed character

Tags: c, char, eof

today i just lay on my bed meditating programming stuff when an idea flows into my mind which i can't solve with my own ability.Below is the Question.

#### I read a book that explain why EOF value is -1 and the explanation is as follow :

*Why -1?Normally getchar() returns a value in the range 0 through 127 , because those are values corresponding to the standard character set , but it might return values from 0 through 255 if the system recognizes an extended character set . In either case , the value -1 does not correspond to any character , so it can be used to signal the end of file.*

1.)It is weird for the statement above because i remember besides signed integer , signed character is also one type of variable exist in C , so that's mean the value from -128 to 127 can be used.But why still the book mention -1 does not contradict to any character use for keyboard input??

Comment: EOF isn't a value, it's a concept. It can be realised in many different ways.

Comment: The EOF OP is referring to **is a value**. It's required to be negative and usually defined as -1.

Comment: I think your book is poorly written and misleading. `getchar` is equally usable on binary streams where any value representable in `unsigned char` might appear. However negative values cannot appear. This is why `EOF` is specified to be negative and why `getchar` returns `int` rather than `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard doesn't say it's `-1`.

> `EOF` which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and
>   a negative value, that is returned by several functions to indicate
>   end-of-ﬁle, that is, no more input from a stream

It's not a value that you can read from a file. It's an "out of band" value that `getc` and such can't return in any case other than "end of file".

Comment: However if they would use any other value for that then a lot of currently working programs would be broken because they use literal -1 value instead of EOF constant (yes, these programs are not portable because of this but we do keep backwards compatibility). Additionally if EOF constant was changed it would break ABI of many libraries even if they used EOF constant.

Comment: This is probably true but silly. The correct test for `EOF` is not `==EOF` but simply `<0`...it's smaller (in source and binary), simpler, and robust against any change in the value of `EOF`.

Comment: @R.. I've never seen a test for EOF other than `== EOF` or `!= EOF`, nor can I think of a good reason to use anything else.

Comment: `jl` is smaller/simpler/faster than `cmp ; je`. This is x86 code but the same principle applies on most ISAs.

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers you've gotten has mentioned a point that (at least IMO) is crucial.

When you read a character, the value is read as an `unsigned char`, and converted from there to `int` (§7.19.7.1/2):

> If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a
>   next character is present, the fgetc function obtains that character as an unsigned
>   char converted to an int and advances the associated file position indicator for the
>   stream (if defined).

This particular quote is for `fgetc` -- `getc`, `getchar`, and `fread` are all required to read data as if by calling `fgetc`.

This does implicitly (at least sort of) assume that `char` has a smaller range than `int`, so the conversion to `int` allows at least one value to be represented that couldn't have come from the file. Elsewhere, the standard denies that as a requirement, but I think that denial is unrealistic -- I'm pretty sure an implementation with `char` and `int` the same size would break *vast* amounts of code.

Answer (score 3):

[getchar](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getchar/) actually returns an `int` which means it has more than 8 bits.  If `getchar` returns a number between 0 and 255 (inclusive), then you know it returned a valid byte from the file you were reading.  If it returns -1 you know you reached the end of the file.  Because the value is an `int`, -1 is guaranteed to not be equal to any value between 0 and 255.

Answer (score 1):

`getchar()` returns an int which contains either a plain (unsigned) char or EOF, so there is no problem.

Comment: This is not correct, getchar() returns an int.... http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getchar/

Comment: I know it was just wrong phrasing, I immediately fixed it. you're fast ;)

Comment: Sorry if I was being offensive :)

Answer (score 0):

That's why getchar() returns an int. If it returned signed char you wouldn't be able to differentiate between EOF and -1 character (128 from extended set), if it returned unsigned char then -1 wouldn't make any sense. However getchar() returns int and if it's in range 0 to 255 it is a character but if it returns -1 then it's EOF

Answer (score 0):

getchar() returns an int. -1 for EOF, or 0 through 255. the int type is big enough to not have conflicts with those.