# What does putc() return in c?

Tags: c, ascii, eof, non-ascii-characters, stdio

I was willing to know what does `putc()` return. I was going through the following link:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_putc.htm. Now if `putc()` returns `EOF` on error, then a natural question is what does it return on end of file? for that I wrote the following in dev c++:

## Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ch = EOF;
    printf("%d\n", putc(ch, stdout));
    printf("hello %d", EOF);

    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
255
hello -1
```

This is a little bit weird. Can anyone help me out ? `EOF` is not an ASCII character as stated in [What is the ascii value of EOF in c.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622699/what-is-the-ascii-value-of-eof-in-c/35640814#35640814) then why `255` (yes its not ASCII) in the first line and `-1` in second?

Comment: `char ch=EOF;` <- `EOF` might be unrepresentable in `char`. It's some `int` constant.

Comment: ok i see that is why return type of putc() is unsigned char .... But why there are 2 different values is still a question .

Comment: Return type is `int`. *This function returns the character written as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on error.* `EOF` has the value `-1` and this cannot be an `unsigned char` cast to `int`.

Comment: The return value of `putc` is of type `int`. Where did you see that it is `unsigned char`?

Comment: sorry @WeatherVane is right,according to the link given it's unsigned char cast to an int.

Comment: If you really want to experiment with the C standard library, think seriously about using a C compiler.

Comment: There are man pages....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EOF is -1 as you already have probably already found out. So if you `putc(EOF,stdout)` then you see `255` in the output because -1 is converted to `unsigned char` before printing.

Comment: AFAIK, the standard doesn't require a specific value for `EOF`. `-1` is just commonly used, as it must be a value different from any character value as `unsigned char`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: `EOF` must also be negative.

Comment: @vasek: The OP does not write `putc(EOF,stdout)`, he writes `putc(ch, stdout)` and `ch` is an `unsigned char` with value `(unsigned char)EOF`, `255` on his system.  `putc(EOF, stdout)` would have the same beavior because the argument is converted as `unsigned char` as you wrote.

Comment: Actually `ch` was declared as `char`, therefore signed.

Comment: @vasek: oops you are correct! but the argument is converted to `unsigned char` anyway.  And `char` might be unsigned by default, which after all is the only consistent choice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

According to [fputc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputc) documentation on cppreference.com, the character is internally converted to `unsigned char`:

> Internally, the character is converted to unsigned char just before
>   being written.

If you now have a (probably signed) character, and you assign `char ch = EOF`, and if `EOF` is actually `-1`, then converting `(char)-1` into `(unsigned char)-1` gives `255`, which is then passed back as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

From [a `putc()` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/putc):

> `fputc()`, `putc()` and `putchar()` return the character written as an **unsigned** *char* cast to an *int* or `EOF` on error.

(emphasis mine)

`EOF` is an `int` constant that is different from any character value, so a natural choice could be `-1` (and many implementations use this).

Now, if your `char` is *signed*, converting `EOF` to `char` will still be `-1`. But the function uses **unsigned char** for characters, so it returns `255` (this would be the same value interpreted as *unsigned*, assuming the signed value was stored in 2's complement and your `char` has 8 bits).

---

Just use the functions the way they are *documented*: Pass `unsigned char` for printing (a character constant is fine) and take the return value as an `int`. if the return value isn't `EOF`, **then** you can interpret it as an `unsigned char`.