# Where can I find EOF definition in stdio.h of llvm?

Tags: c++

I am digging around C++ I/O documentation.

I can find `EOF` definition in `stdio.h` of VC++ but can't find it in `stdio.h` of llvm https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/stdio.h

[image]

---

By the way, from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits it says
[image]

So for `char`, `std::char_traits::eof` returns `EOF` which is `-1`. Also from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/eof, it says :

> Returns a value not equivalent to any valid value of type char_type.

So here's what I deduce: `-1` is not a valid value of type char_type(`char`)?

How come? In VC++, `char` is signed, so `-1` should be valid for `char`.

Comment: Hi, please define `valid`, As far as I know, EOF is not a "char" as in a character in a string (like `\0`), it's a return code.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I am also wondering what `valid` means from the doc. It simply says *Returns a value not equivalent to any **valid** value of type char_type.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the ascii value of EOF in c.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622699/what-is-the-ascii-value-of-eof-in-c). [...]`The actual value of EOF is system defined and not part of the standard.`[...]

Comment: Ah, yes... I miss-read that part a bit.

Comment: Nevertheless, I think something is not completely right: -1, 8bit ANSI (depending on code page) is: `ÿ`, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Comment: @Stefan see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/to_int_type the integer representation of characters typically uses `unsigned char` so for `char` the integer values for characters are 0-255 with EOF being a negative number (usually -1)

Comment: @user1810087 its not a duplicated. I am not asking the value of EOF but want to know the meaning of *valid* from the doc

Comment: @Rick **possible** duplicate is not a duplicate. EOF is not part of the standard means there is no **the** doc. I've linked the other question because you can get there some decent answers (at least partially) covering your question. E.g: the answer from [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622741/1810087) [...]`because the character read could have any value in the range of unsigned char`[...]

Comment: Looking at the header file itself (linked in the question), it is easy to see that it `#include`s other files.   The definition of `EOF` is probably in one of those other files.   Note this is specific to that particular implementation - the standard says nothing about how standard headers achieve their required effects (definitions, etc).

Comment: @AlanBirtles The link to `to_int_type` is very helpful. Thank you. Now I understand a bit more.So whether `char` is signed or not, and whether if negative value of signed `char` maps to real character , it eventually converts to `unsigned char` which is between `0-255` (then converts to `int`) , so define `EOF` as a negative  value can distinguish them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you mention, https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/stdio.h , picks up EOF from the C library using this line:

```
#include_next <stdio.h>
```

LLVM does not provide a C library, so it will be whatever you have on your system. For example, on a Linux, it will typically be GNU libc, which defines EOF [here](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/libio/stdio.h#L102-L104)

```
/* The value returned by fgetc and similar functions to indicate the
   end of the file.  */
#define EOF (-1)
```